# Visual Studio "synchronize" multiple projects within one solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, version-control, projects-and-solutions

I am writing my own C++ project library in visual studio (couple of projects that consist of *cpp, *.h files, NOT an actual .lib file). Each of these projects is located in single Visual Studio "solution".

When I needed to use a code from one project in another, I just copied it. But that was short term solution. Now my library has grown both in size and functionality, and because of code duplication I ended up with dozens of different versions of the same file.

That single solution serve me as a playground // test ground for new ideas. I am developing projects not libs. Currently it holds about 50 projects.

I am working on visual studio 2015.

---

Lets say I have setup like this:

1. **DataIO** project located in `*/Solution/#DataInputAndOutput/DataIO/DataIO.h`
   consist both of DataIO.h and DataIO.cpp
2. **Foo** project located in `*/Solution/#Foo/Foo/Foo.h`
   consist both of Foo.h and Foo.cpp

### DataIO.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __DATA_IO_H__
#define __DATA_IO_H__
// ...

extern FILE * const logFile;

// Bunch of function declarations
#endif // !__DATA_IO_H__
```

I know that this is not a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" but my problem lies in logistic of things, not things themselves. And I believe that my description is sufficient.

---

**Problem #1:** In `Foo.cpp` I `#include "DataIO.h"` (with is possible because i added additional include directories in `Foo` project setup) But whenever I try to compile `Foo` I am given following error: `unresolved external symbol` for every function declaration inside `DataIO.h` and that one external variable. **How Can I Fix this problem? Do I need to create a `DataIO.lib` to keep things straight?**

I tried to add `DataIO.h` and `DataIO.cpp` into `Foo` project directly (NOT copy it, just add it into project) but that seems like a bad idea...

Comment: What are you developing?  A library or a project(s)?

Comment: @AnonMail  I am developing projects. In my "solution" there are about 50 of them.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? If 2015+, I highly recommend using "Shared Items Project"s.

Comment: @MichaelGunter its 2015. Sory i missed that fact in question. Edited.

Comment: Just a suggestion (it can be considered total overkill).  Always when developing a new project create a lib first.  If you want an application create a new project write a `main` and link the lib.  Change your mind and want a dll same, new project `DllMain` and link the lib.  Want to reuse the code in another project include the header(s) and link the lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying out the new "Shared Items Project" in VS2015+. A Shared Items Project is literally just a set of files. The project itself doesn't build anything. In fact, there are no (or almost no) compilation or linkage settings in a Shared Items Project -- those settings come the the project that references the Shared Items Project. When you reference a Shared Items Project from some other project FOO, the build of FOO happens as if the files of the Shared Items Project are items of the referencing project.

Short of that, you can set up your shared projects to build .libs and then use Project References within Visual Studio to automatically set up the linkage. I think you have to manually set up the include paths when doing this, though.

Comment: I have one question thou... Lets say that i am working with C / C++ cuda and I wish to create "shared item project`s" from cuda code. That should not be a problem?

 If i understand it right a way in with project is build is determined by the project which is referring. Not a project that is referred to.

Comment: I don't know anything about CUDA, but if that is just a set of C / C++ artifacts (headers, libs, etc), then yes, you should be able to set up the necessary references in your main project, and the Shared Items Projects should just work. If you have a single Shared Items Project that has a dependency like this, I think it is possible to put compiler/linker settings in the Shared Items Project manually, so that any project that references the Shared Items Project gets all the necessary settings. To do that sort of thing, try moving parts of the main project XML into the Shared Items Project XML.

Comment: I have been rearranging projects in my "lib" for last an hour. And i cannot tell how thankful I am. Thank you for this idea. 
Btw I have checked does it work with cuda: it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah! I like Shared Items Projects too. The only downside I've encountered thus far is that it leads to filename collision. If the shared project has a file with the same name as the referencing project (or another shared project), the compiler can't deal with that. With pre-compiled .libs, that isn't a problem. But in practice, this is rarely an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to factor out common code into a library so the common code resides in one place.  And then have your projects use the library - via an include file and linking with said library.